# Excel to nested list (duplicate indexes)

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have an excel file with columns :

```
Name, Date Visited, Date Left, Amount
```

The thing is, the Name field can contain multiple same entries and I need to create a list for that name, something like:

```
{ Name:
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
  Name:
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
   {Date Visited, Date Left, Amount},
}
```

I tried creating a dictionary but it removes duplicate names.

Comment: How about a list of dictionaries. Also, I have no idea what you are talking about based on the information provided. There is no sample data illustrating the issue, and no code to demonstrate what you have tried. We are not mind readers here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  Specifically, this is your second question which contains absolutely NO code.  Code is the language we speak and without code it is unlikely we will understand what you trying to say.  Please read and understand these links, they will make you more successful here on Stackoverflow.